# Malloc_Debug on android System Library for memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am building a customized `MediaCas` plugin on Android P and run on emulator , i need to setup memory leak detector tool on my `MediaCas` plugin to check memory corruption,leaks etc . I tried Malloc Debug mentioned in Android developer's page

- I was able to set prop for the mediacas process, but i don't see any logs in logcat related memory leaks , Does logs are dumped in any other file?
- Any other tool to check memory leaks for android system library